# Show that the bounded linear operator on sequence space l2 is not invertible

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $c = (1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...)\in \ell_{\infty}$ and let $T\in B(\ell_2)$ be defined by $T(\{x_n\}) = \{c_nx_n\}.$

Show that $T$ is not invertible.

I know that a an invertible operator must be one-to-one and onto, and $T(\{x_n\}) = \{c_nx_n\}$ is continuous if and only is $c_n$ is bounded.

But how do you show that $T$ does not have an inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is not onto because $\left(1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots\right)\in \ell_2$ is not in its range.

Answer (score 3):

If $T$ was invertible, it inverse should be $U(x_n)=x_n/c_n$. But $U$ is not bounded.

Comment: Also a good answer. Thanks.